# Apply package mpfr for a function in R

Tags: r, mpfr

I want to apply package  mpfr for a function as follows:

```
     f1  =function(x) exp(x)
```

if for example `x = c(-1500, -2000, -6400, -7200)`

```
     > x = c(-1500, -2000, -6400, -7200)
     >  mpfr(f1(x), precBits=64)
     4 'mpfr' numbers of precision  64   bits 
     [1] 0 0 0 0
```

I would like to get the values of function f1 even if its so small, how can I get it in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64 bits is not a whole lot.  But primarily, you've made a mistake many of us did:  the value of `f1(x)` is already zero because  it's calculated *before* being converted into a bignum.

Try it this way:

```
> exp(mpfr(c(-1000,-5000),200))
2 'mpfr' numbers of precision  200   bits 
[1]  5.0759588975494567652918094795743369193055992828928373618323948e-435
[2] 3.3696941483089175144500323238132201679550979027292655581078801e-2172
```